# multiples view Controller in the same class

Tags: objective-c, class, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uibutton

Is possible  multiples view Controller each view has different animations one view controller principal  has a custom menu navigation To see the other views  you change the views  But the menu bar be kept in place without moving

tab bar controller not work because the menu navigation is very very special

Any ideas please

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at containing view controllers and `childViewController`, here is a good tutorial:

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/containing-viewcontrollers/